# Tensorflow 2 second order derivative after applied gradients in eager execution

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement Model Agnostic Meta Learning (MAML) in Tensorflow 2. 
For this algorithm a second order derivative is calculated in the form:

```
for multiple sets, each with an individual model:
  1. Determine the loss for a training set
  2. Determine the gradients for this loss w.r.t. the model
  3. Apply the gradients (theta' <- theta-alpha*gradients)

4. Determine the loss for an evaluation set for each of the updated models
5. Determine the gradient of the sum of the losses (4) w.r.t. the global model
```

I am trying to implement this in tensorflow 2 with `GradientTape` but the second gradient is always an array of `None`s.

My implementation looks like this:

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as meta_update_tape:
    # inner loop (for all tasks)
    for bi in range(batch_size):

       # the training and evaluation batches
       x_i, y_i, x_i_prime, y_i_prime = dataset.batch_with_eval()

       # reset the weights to to current global weights before training for this batch
       model_copy = copy_model_weights(source=model, target=model_copy)

       # Compute loss using theta_global for D_i
       with tf.GradientTape() as inner_update_tape:
           inner_loss, _, _ = compute_loss(model_copy, x_i, y_i)

       gradients_inner_update = inner_update_tape.gradient(inner_loss, model_copy.trainable_variables)

       # update model parameters (apply theta_i_prime)
       # inner_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_inner_update, model_copy.trainable_variables))
       conv_layers  = [i for i,var in enumerate(model_copy.trainable_variables) if var.name.startswith('conv2d')]
       for layer in conv_layers:
           model_copy.trainable_variables[layer].assign(tf.subtract(model.trainable_variables[layer], tf.multiply(0.4, gradients_inner_update[layer])))

       # calculate loss with theta_i_prime with eval set
       loss_eval, accuracy_eval, _ = compute_loss(model_copy, x_i_prime, y_i_prime)

       batch_losses.append(loss_eval)

   sum_losses = tf.reduce_sum(batch_losses) / tf.cast(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

# calculate gradient over all losses w.r.t global theta (trainable variables for global model)
gradients_meta_update = meta_update_tape.gradient(sum_losses, model.trainable_variables)

# gradients_meta_update is [None, None, None, ...]
```

I've tried:

- to run it without the loop (just one batch)
- to have the sum of the losses outside the outer tape
- to apply the gradients for the inner update with a SGD optimizer (this is what I would prefer to do)
- not to apply the inner gradient at all
- have the inner tape with the option `persistent=True`
- watch the `model.trainable_variables` in the outer tape explicitly

I'm running out of ideas and the documentation does not help me, so I appreciate every suggestion.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is a bug on TensorFlow 2 when you try to update the weights of a Keras model accessing its *trainable_variables* attribute (it also happens to the attribute *trainable_weights*). It seems the model's weights lose their gradient tracking after being updated through that approach.

Instead of accessing `model_copy.trainable_variables` to update the model's weights, you should iterate directly on the model's layers and update their variables invoking their attributes. For instance, assuming your model has only Conv2D layers, you could use the following code to update their weights:

```
grad_idx = 0
for idx, layer in enumerate(model_copy.layers):
    if hasattr(model_copy.layers[idx], 'kernel'):
        updated_model.layers[layer_idx].kernel = tf.subtract(model.trainable_variables[layer], tf.multiply(0.4, gradients_inner_update[grad_idx])))
        grad_idx += 1
```

Be aware that `kernel` is an attribute of the Conv2D layer, which is listed on its `trainable_weights` attribute. So, you also should update **all the other attributes** whose name is also listed on the layer's `trainable_weights` (for instance, in the case of Dense layers, you also must update the attributes `weights` and `bias`). That strategy works for other Keras layers, such as `Dense` and `BatchNormalization`, for example.